# How data-to works as attribute of button in phoenix?

Tags: phoenix-framework

`Phoenix.HTML.Link` provide a `button` helper which will generate a html code below:

```
button("hello", to: "/world", method: :get, class: "btn")
#=> <button class="btn" data-method="get" data-to="/world">hello</button>
```

The `data-to` will navigate to the new page when clicking the button. How is it work? I suspected it should have some js code to handle this action but I couldn't found in documentation or source code.

The reason I want to find it is because it generates the new URL with `_csrf_token=&_method=get` and I want to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.

The button action is handled by the [`phoenix_html.js`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/master/priv/static/phoenix_html.js#L27), which generates a `form` object and submit the form.